# Which command to get words from table?

Tags: pgfplotstable, database

I have the following table:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{table.dat}
cane 1.5
gatto 3
\end{filecontents*}
```

from which I have to take cells separately for the plot. The numeric values can be easily gotten through the command `\pgfplotstablegetelem{<row>}{<column>}\of\table`but it seems that the command works only for numeric value and not with words (because it is a PGF Math Package).

So which command can I use to get the element "cane" and "gatto"?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It is not a PGF math package and numerical or not doesn't matter. You might have been doing something else.

It works with the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
cane 1.5
gatto 3
}\mytable

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\mytable
\pgfplotsretval

\pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{[index]0}\of\mytable
\pgfplotsretval

\end{document}
```

which gives cane and gatto as the output